# Vs Code Installation

Tags: visual-studio-code

Hii. I have installed vs code previously. And then uninstalled it. Again when i am trying to install vs code it is installing in that my previously speciified location (Not in C ) automatically, And there is no option present to change the location. Because it's installing automatically without asking for the location.

I have tried by deleting the all files of vs code or path, not working.
Please help me.

I have tried by deleting the all files of vs code or path, not working.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the VS Code folder from AppData:

Press Windows key + R to open the Run dialog box.
Type %appdata% and press Enter. This will open the AppData folder.
Look for a folder called "Code" and delete it.